# in fact or however?

Tags: transitions

> In order to save an endangered species, preservationists must study it in detail. (______), scientific information about some endangered animals is scarce.
>
> A. However
>   B. Therefore
>   C. In fact
>   D. Likewise

In my opinion, I think C is the correct answer, but book says that it is A. Which one is correct and explain to me why the answer C is not the correct one.

Comment: I would think A or C could fits the sense sentence. However, if A was correct, it should have been followed by a comma. In the absence of a comma, I agree that C is correct.

Comment: I disagree with @James and think that A is the better option though there should be a comma in the second sentence. The two sentences are opposites - the first one suggests that preservationists need the scientific information (to study species) and the second says that they do not have the needed scientific information. Such contrasts/‘flips’ should be prefaced with ‘however’. ‘In fact’ is used when the second sentence elaborates on or follows from the first (e.g. Upon hearing the news, Owen got really angry. In fact, he became so angry that he turned red)

Comment: Sorry i forgot the comma.

Comment: I agree that only A is possible too. In the first part they stress the importance of studying something in detail and in the second part they state that currently it's not really possible due to the scarcity of information on the subject.

Comment: The difference is that ***in fact*** means ***contrary to what one might expect*** in a "general" sense, whereas ***however*** specifically means ***contrary to / detracting from the implications of the immediately preceding utterance***. Obviously if we're told preservationists need to study something, the fact that the relevant information is scarce will hamper their efforts, which is why it's appropriate to use a contrastive conjunction such as ***however, but, yet***. Which doesn't make ***in fact*** actually "wrong". It's just "less obviously right".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In order to save an endangered species, preservationists must study it in detail. (______), scientific information about some endangered animals is scarce.
>
> A. However B. Therefore C. In fact D. Likewise

I agree with the book - it is **however** in this case.

Normally, "however" separates two statements that are *contrary*, but not mutually exclusive. For example:

> I normally drink tea. However, today I had a coffee.

In your example there are two statements - first of all that an endangered species must be studied ***in detail*** in order to save it, and secondly that information about some some such species ***is scarce***, meaning that it *hasn't* been studied in detail. These two ideas are contrary, but not mutually exclusive (some species have been studied, some have not). This is why I believe "however" is the appropriate word to use here.

"Therefore" is used to show that a follow up statement logically follows the first - that is not the case here.

"Likewise" is used to show that two statements are essentially the same, or share something in common. Again, that is not the case here.

I can understand why you might think "in fact" fits, and to be honest I think it would go unchallenged it it was used! But normally "in fact" would be used to introduce a *supporting statement* that upholds what went before it. For example:

> Homelessness is on the increase in Manchester. **In fact**, nearly twice as many people slept on the street this year as the year before.

You can see how the "fact" supports the previous statement. In your example, the "fact" that some species have not been studied does nothing to support the previous statement that endangered species require further studies, and that is why I do not believe it is the correct answer.

The only situation where you might use "in fact" to *contradict* a previous statement is if you had already introduced some *doubt*. For example you might say "*The woman claimed she was 28 years old. In fact she was 40*". This is because you only stated somebody else's *claim*. But nobody makes a statement of fact of their own and then contradicts it in the next breath, and again, your example is presented as entirely factual from beginning to end.

Comment: Note also that "in fact" *may* be used to contradict the previous statement, but usually only if it is a statement about someone else's beliefs, e.g., "The *National Geographic* says that potatoes are good for you.  In fact, many health issues are caused by excessive potato consumption."  [Contrived example.]

Comment: @HarryJohnston And sometimes both are used: "However, in fact many health issues ..."